# Python: google voice recognition stopping the button animation

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a program that will recognize what I'm saying and eventually will send it to the microcontroller I'm working with. I just finished writing the voice recognition app. However, I have a problem, the google voice recognition library enters a loop while it listens and it delays the press animation of the button.
Any suggestions for a way to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

import speech_recognition as sr

KV = '''
   MDIconButton:

   icon: "microphone"
   user_font_size : 64
   pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
   on_press: app.callback()
'''
r = sr.Recognizer()
to_send = ""
text = ""


class ButtonApp(MDApp):

   def build(self):
       return Builder.load_string(KV)


   def callback(self):
      global text
      try:
          with sr.Microphone() as source:
              audio_data = r.record(source, duration=2)
              print("Recognizing...")
              text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
      except:
          print("couldn't recognize you")

      global to_send
      if text == "forward":
          to_send = "f"

      elif text == "backwards":
          to_send = "b"

      elif text == "right":
          to_send = "r"

      elif text == "left":
          to_send = "l"

      else:
          to_send = text

      print(to_send)


root = ButtonApp()

root.run()
```

Comment: Is the code complete? There is no `run` method of class `ButtonApp` or am I missing something?

Comment: There is, look at the bottom.
The code works its just the animation that's delayed